# Sum Pandas DF value in additional new columns according to a condition on a datetime column

Tags: python, pandas

I've a simple Pandas Dataframe with four columns:

NRAPPOR;  DSCARAT;    IQTACAP;  IQTAINT

2;     2006-12-31;         0.00;       60.00
 2;      2007-01-31;      270.75;      150.05
 2;       2007-02-28;     272.78;      148.02
 2;        2007-03-31;     274.82;     145.98
 2;         2007-04-30;    276.88;     143.92
... ... ... ...
5731;      2016-11-17;    1760.00;     240.00
5731;      2018-11-17;    1800.00;     200.00
5731;      2019-11-17;    1850.00;     150.00
5731;      2020-11-17;    1900.00;     100.00
5731;      2021-11-17;    1950.00;    50.00

where:
 - NRAPPOR = loan ID
 - NSCARAT = installment expiry date
 - IQTACAP = Principal portion of installment
 - IQTAINT = Interset portion of installment

**For each NRAPP, I'd like to sum of  IQTACAP and IQTAINT values in four distinct totalizers according to whether or not DSCARAT is less than the threshold date ('2020-03-17'**
I want to sum IQTACAP in totCapOverdue if DSCADRAT is <= than the threshold date ('2020-03-17'
I want to sum IQTACAP in totCapToExpire  if DSCADRAT is > than the threshold date ('2020-03-17'
I want to sum IQTAINT in totIntOverdue if DSCADRAT is <= than the threshold date ('2020-03-17'
I want to sum IQTAINT in totIntToExpire  if DSCADRAT is > than the threshold date ('2020-03-17'

**I'd like to obtain a New DF with 5 columns; NRAPPOR and the four totalizers**

'This is my barbaric code:

```
'set threshold date
dataSoglia = '2020-03-17' 

totCapOverdue = 0
totIntOverdue = 0
totCapToExpire = 0
totIntToExpire = 0
rapportoPrev = 0

for index, row in df1.iterrows():

    'if NRAPPORT changes, I print the totalizer

    'I would prefer to obtain a new Dataframe with NRAPPOR and the four totalizer as new columns

    if((index[0]!=rapportoPrev) & (rapportoPrev!=0)):
        print(rapportoPrev,'\t', 'capOverdue: ', totCapOverdue, '\t', 'intOverdue: ', totIntOverdue, '\t','capToExpire: ', totCapToExpire,  '\t', 'intpToExpire: ', totIntToExpire)    


    'set totalizer to zero
    totCapOverdue = 0
    totIntOverdue = 0
    totCapToExpire = 0
    totIntToExpire = 0

if (index[1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  <= dataSoglia):
    totCapOverdue += row['IQTACAP']
    totIntOverdue += row['IQTAINT']
else:
    totCapToExpire += row['IQTACAP']
    totIntToExpire += row['IQTAINT']
rapportoPrev = index[0]
dataPrev=index[1]
```

**This is my output:**
2    capOverdue:  19999.999999999993     intOverdue:  4887.200000000001      capToExpire:  0     intpToExpire:  0
3    capOverdue:  123156.18000000002     intOverdue:  70519.02   capToExpire:  26843.820000000003    intpToExpire:  1528.9799999999996
4    capOverdue:  30000.0    intOverdue:  4965.180000000001      capToExpire:  0     intpToExpire:  0
5    capOverdue:  6000.000000000002      intOverdue:  167.1      capToExpire:  0     intpToExpire:  0
6    capOverdue:  18000.0    intOverdue:  2111.89    capToExpire:  0     intpToExpire:  0
7    capOverdue:  50000.00000000003      intOverdue:  8104.3     capToExpire:  0     intpToExpire:  0
8    capOverdue:  50000.00000000003      intOverdue:  15711.999999999996     capToExpire:  0     intpToExpire:  0
9    capOverdue:  70000.0    intOverdue:  18213.110000000004     capToExpire:  0     intpToExpire:  0
...

'Is there a better way to di that?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, it can be done using a combination of DataFrame methods `groupby`, `apply` and `query` (and maybe also converting dates to Timestamp type if they are string). If you can edit your question and add an example of the `df1` dataframe that one can copy and create, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks Itamar.
How can I add a sample of my dataframe to facilitate you?

Comment: Maybe it's easier if you just tell me the datatype of the dates column, is it pandas Timestamp? datetime? something else? I see it has a `strftime` method but just to be sure

Comment: Yes, it is a datetime

Comment: NRAPPOR             int64  
DSCARAT    datetime64[ns]  
IQTACAP           float64  
IQTAINT           float64  

I'm sorry, but, as you can see, it's my first question on SOF

Comment: np, one last remark, when you write about a dataframe in SO question, it's helpful to mention which are indices and which are columns. I can guess it from your code but it's better not having to guess.. (posting answer soon)

Comment: To @ItamarKatz point, please see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for future pandas questions; reproducible samples make it much easier on you and your potential helpers to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

First I create a pandas DataFrame with subset of your data (that's what you can do in your questions to make your code reproducible):

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[2, '2006-12-31', 0.0, 60.0], 
        [2, '2007-01-31', 270.75, 150.05],
        [2, '2007-02-28', 272.78, 148.02],
        [2, '2007-03-31', 274.82, 145.98],
        [2, '2007-04-30', 276.88, 143.92],
        [5731, '2016-11-17', 1760.0, 240.0],
        [5731, '2018-11-17', 1800.0, 200.0],
        [5731, '2019-11-17', 1850.0, 150.0],
        [5731, '2020-11-17', 1900.0, 100.0],
        [5731, '2021-11-17', 1950.0, 50.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['NRAPPOR', 'DSCARAT', 'IQTACAP','IQTAINT'])
df = df.set_index('NRAPPOR')
#--- convert string to datetime
df['DSCARAT'] = df['DSCARAT'].apply(lambda ts: pd.Timestamp(ts))
```

Now I use pandas `groupby` to split the table according to the ID, and apply a function using `apply` to each group: query for the relevant dates and sum:

```
th_date = pd.Timestamp('2007-03-01')
overdue = df.groupby('NRAPPOR').apply(lambda g: g.query('DSCARAT < @th_date').sum())
expire = df.groupby('NRAPPOR').apply(lambda g: g.query('DSCARAT >= @th_date').sum())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Itamar  Is it possible to obtain the totalizers in the same row, to be exported in a CSV file?

Comment: And is it possible to avoid a total for DSCARAT? What does it represent?  NRAPPOR         
2        IQTACAP                 543.53
         IQTAINT                 358.07
3        DSCARAT    2007-02-26 00:00:00
         IQTACAP                  533.6
         IQTAINT                    700
4        IQTACAP                 406.12
         IQTAINT                 390.08
5        IQTACAP                 238.87
         IQTAINT                  77.73

Comment: You can drop the total of DSCARAT as you don't need it. And as for combining the output to a single dataframe that can be exported to csv, you should get familiar with pandas and combining/joining/concatenating arrays.

Comment: Itamar, this is overdue output:
{(2, 'IQTACAP'): 19999.999999999993,
 (2, 'IQTAINT'): 4887.200000000001,
 (3, 'IQTACAP'): 123156.18000000002,
 (3, 'IQTAINT'): 70519.02,
 (4, 'IQTACAP'): 30000.0,
 (4, 'IQTAINT'): 4965.18
...

And this is 
expire output:
{(2, 'DSCARAT'): 0.0,
 (2, 'IQTACAP'): 0.0,
 (2, 'IQTAINT'): 0.0,
 (3, 'IQTACAP'): 26843.82,
 (3, 'IQTAINT'): 1528.98,
 (4, 'DSCARAT'): 0.0,
 (4, 'IQTACAP'): 0.0,
 (4, 'IQTAINT'): 0.0,
 (5, 'IQTAINT'): 0.0,
 (6, 'DSCARAT'): 0.0 ..
 (6, 'IQTACAP'): 0.0,
 (6, 'IQTAINT'): 0.0 
...
Why DSCARAT appears? How to drop it?